# Best UX pattern for uploading multiple pictures on a mosaic

Tags: physical, files, interactive-ui, upload, multiple-screens

I am building an online print on demand tool. The final result is a physical object with several faces, each face containing an user-uploaded picture.

I want users to be able to upload a pictures from their own device, and choose on which face each picture is going to be shown.

Ideally I would just show a rendering of the final product, users can move this rendering around with their mouse or by swiping.

Clicking on a face would show a file upload browser dialog, and once a picture has been selected and uploaded the object render would display the user image on the selected face.

Once all available faces have been filled, a "continue to checkout" button gets enabled and allows users to proceed with their journey.

I'm not really satisfied with this solution, which seems clunky and not user-friendly on mobile. Am I missing something? Is there a better, more straightforward solution to this? Am I unnecessarily complicating things, and if that is so what would be the best way out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes it not user-friendly on mobile? What is clunky about it?

Comment: it would help having an example or at least the wireframe of your solution :) Without this i just can ask, have you tried like a bulk images import and then choosing on which face each picture is going to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can certainly use basic t-shirt design apps as an inspiration for different ways you can upload images. There is usually a larger preview window where you can see all the different sides of the t-shirt, and then there's an input area for each side of the t-shirt that you can use to upload the image that you can iterate or switch between using icons or a list of fields.

On mobile view you probably can't use the preview of the object to navigate through all the fields to upload the images, but at least you'll still have a list of the faces for the object and its associated input fields for the images. That way you can still have the preview of the object once all the images are uploaded (or it can be updated as you upload each image).

Perhaps if you only have a small number of objects that are simple enough to flatten out and display like this example from [Roblox](https://create.roblox.com/docs/art/accessories/classic-clothing)?